# Решить в целых числах уравнение: (ax+b) / (cx+d) = 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решить в целых числах уравнение: (ax+b) / (cx+d) =0

Формат ввода

Вводятся 4 числа: a,b,c,d; c и d не равны нулю одновременно.

Формат вывода

Необходимо вывести все решения, если их число конечно, “NO” (без кавычек), если решений нет, и “INF” (без кавычек), если решений бесконечно много.

Тест 1

Входные данные:

```
1
1
2
2
```

Вывод программы:

```
NO
```

Тест 2

Входные данные:

```
2
-4
7
1
```

Вывод программы:

```
2
```

Помогите составить код на Python

Answer (score 2):

```
a, b, c, d = int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
if a == 0 and b == 0:
    print('INF')
elif a == 0 or b * c == a * d:
    print('NO')
elif b % a == 0:
    x = -b // a
    print(x)
else:
    print('NO')
```